# Running a Cygwin compiled executable with gettext/libintl in MSYS2 shells (cygheap read copy failed)?

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, msys2

This seems to be a similar issue to the one listed in ["cygheap read copy failed ... Win32 error 6" after linking program with gettext · Issue #1794 · msys2/MSYS2-packages · GitHub](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1794), but I cannot find a solution for my use case.

I'm working on Windows 10, and below is a bash script, that generates a simple test .c file that uses libintl, and builds it as an executable under Cygwin, while statically linking the Cygwin libintl and libiconv libraries. Simply copy the script and run it with `bash test_intl.sh` in a Cygwin shell (Cygwin64 Terminal):

`test_intl.sh`

```bash
# example from https://localazy.com/blog/make-multi-language-application-in-c-gettext-localazy
mkdir -p /tmp/testintl/locales/en/LC_MESSAGES
cd /tmp/testintl
cat > testintl.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define _(String) gettext(String)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int opt;
  char *filename = NULL;

  int i_flag = 0;
  int g_flag = 0;

  bindtextdomain ("base", "./locales/");
  textdomain ("base");

  while ( (opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hi:g:")) != -1 ) {
    switch(opt) {
      case 'h':
        printf(_("\033[1;37mThis application does absolutely nothing.\n\n"));
        printf(_("Available options:\n"));
        printf(_("-i <file>\tDoes nothing with specified file. \n"));
        printf(_("-g <file>\tDoes nothing with specified file, but in \033[0;32mgreen color\033[0;37m.\n"));
        break;
      case 'i':
        filename = optarg;
        i_flag = 1;
        break;
      case 'g':
        filename = optarg;
        g_flag = 1;
        break;
      default:
        printf(_("Use -h to display help.\n"));
        return 0;
    }
  }

  if (!i_flag && !g_flag) {
    printf(_("Use -h to display help.\n"));
  }

  if ((i_flag || g_flag) && !filename) {
    printf(_("You must specify a destination file name.\n"));
    return 1;
  }

  if (i_flag) {
    printf(_("Doing nothing with %s file...\n"), filename);
    printf(_("Done.\n"));
  }

  if (g_flag) {
    printf(_("\033[0;32mDoing nothing with %s file...\n"), filename);
    printf(_("Done.\n"));
  }

  return 0;
}
EOF

set -x
xgettext -k_ -o locales/base.pot --language=C testintl.c
msginit --no-translator --input=locales/base.pot --locale=en_US --output=locales/en/base.po
msgfmt --output-file=locales/en/LC_MESSAGES/base.mo locales/en/base.po
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable -std=c99 testintl.c -o testintl.exe /lib/libintl.a /lib/libiconv.a
./testintl.exe -h
# copy dependent libraries:
cp -a /bin/cygwin1.dll .
set +x
exepath=$(readlink -f ./testintl.exe)
echo "EXE location  (cygwin):" $exepath
echo "EXE location (Windows):" $(cygpath -w $exepath)
```

When I run this in Cygwin shell, the output is:

```
user@DESKTOP-PC ~
$ bash test_intl.sh
+ xgettext -k_ -o locales/base.pot --language=C testintl.c
+ msginit --no-translator --input=locales/base.pot --locale=en_US --output=locales/en/base.po
Created locales/en/base.po.
+ msgfmt --output-file=locales/en/LC_MESSAGES/base.mo locales/en/base.po
+ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable -std=c99 testintl.c -o testintl.exe /lib/libintl.a /lib/libiconv.a
+ ./testintl.exe -h
This application does absolutely nothing.

Available options:
-i <file>       Does nothing with specified file.
-g <file>       Does nothing with specified file, but in green color.
Use -h to display help.
+ cp -a /bin/cygwin1.dll .
+ set +x
EXE location  (cygwin): /tmp/testintl/testintl.exe
EXE location (Windows): C:\cygwin64\tmp\testintl\testintl.exe
```

So, the executable clearly works in the Cygwin shell.

I also try running it from the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`):

```
C:\Users\user>C:\cygwin64\tmp\testintl\testintl.exe -h
This application does absolutely nothing.

Available options:
-i <file>       Does nothing with specified file.
-g <file>       Does nothing with specified file, but in green color.
Use -h to display help.
```

So, the executable clearly works in the cmd.exe shell.

Now, I try to run this executable from a MSYS2 shell - either MSYS or MINGW64, makes no difference in behavior:

```
user@DESKTOP-PC 2023-01-15 MINGW64 ~
$ /c/cygwin64/tmp/testintl/testintl.exe -h
      0 [main] testintl (19376) child_copy: cygheap read copy failed, 0x800000000..0x8000105A8, done 0, windows pid 19376, Win32 error 6
    870 [main] testintl 1423 C:\cygwin64\tmp\testintl\testintl.exe: *** fatal error - couldn't create signal pipe, Win32 error 5
```

Clearly, the executable does not run under a MSYS2 shell.

Is there some workaround I can do, so this executable also works under a MSYS2 shell?

Comment: I've never used msys2, but my feeling is that you have to compile and link it separately so that it is available to run in that environment.

Comment: You can use the `ldd` command to see which shared libraries your app uses. E..g. `ldd $(which ls)` in cygwin bash and msys2 bash to see differences. Then do `ldd testintl.exe` in both shells. This may give a clue to what is wrong. You should make two exe's, one for cygwin and one for msys2. Use the msys2 compiler tools, or use the cross-compiler under cygwin to build the app for msys2. BTW, make sure there are no msys2 folders in the path for cygwin bash, and no cygwin folders in the path for msys2 bash. Mix and match is bad news.